# Which question to close?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes we realize too late that a question is a duplicate and some answers are posted.

If a new answer is better than the one associated to the old question what to do?

Which question to close?

How to link questions?

Here is an example:

[LeftMouse focus window without moving cursor](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/42275/23502)

Vs.

[Focus-follows-mode in Neovim?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/41622/23502)

Comment: Yes indeed. The vote the close the old question has not been accepted but as 2 votes. Should I consider that as the good practice?

Comment: :shrug: IMHO, "accepting" doesn't mean much on a meta site. The "close the old one" answer has 4 votes as of right now which seems to be about as many as any answers on this meta ever get, and the corresponding answer on meta.se seems to be the overwhelming favourite there.